# How to make my son stop hitting his playmate?

Tags: toddler, discipline, social-development

My son likes to play with other children, but eventually he hits them when he got mad on them. Then I just get him from their playground and tell him to stay at home and play alone.

Is this the right approach or is there a better one?

Comment: Welcome to Parenting SE! Could you add a few details like the age of your son, please? Also, we have a few similar questions, just check for the tags you used. In general, the [tour] and our [help] are good places to learn more about the site. Again: welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I work in a school and the way we deal with this type of behaviour is to remind the child that they must use "kind hands" when playing with their friends. We set clear rules that if "kind hands" aren't used the child will then be removed from playing with their friend for 5 minutes and have to sit in silence away from everyone. Then they are introduced back into play time, if the behaviour continues they gradually become removed for longer periods of time. They tend to get the picture once they've spent most of the time removed from the situation. I hope this helps :)